# Touch coordinates in a centered and scaled ImageView

Tags: android, touch, imageview

I have a classic `ImageView` that is resized to fit its parent with `match_parent` on both axes and `scaleType` is `fitCenter`.

[image: Screenshot]

The coordinates I get out of an `onTouch` event, however, are relative to the bounds of the `ImageView`. How can I convert them to be relative to the bounds of the image itself?

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing this manually. This is in Scala, but probably easy to translate into Java :

```
// Long press on the screen adds a new interaction at that position
screenView onTouch {
  (v: View, ev: MotionEvent) => {
    // Create the image transformation matrix
    val m = screenView.getImageMatrix
    val d = screenView.getDrawable
    val drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth, d.getIntrinsicHeight)
    val viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, screenView.getWidth, screenView.getHeight)
    m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER)
    m.invert(m)

    // Convert the points inside the image
    val points = Array(ev.getX, ev.getY)
    m mapPoints points

    // Compute normalized coordinates
    current_x = points(0) / d.getIntrinsicWidth
    current_y = points(1) / d.getIntrinsicHeight

    // Only continue if we touched inside the image
    !(current_x >= 0 && current_x <= 1 &&
      current_y >= 0 && current_y <= 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution helped me out. Some improvements: The drawableRect and viewRect are not necessary. The imageView will already have the matrix setup. If the image is not changing, the matrix set up can be moved outside of the the onTouch method.  You will need to make a deep copy of the inverted matrix because it will otherwise reset to its original state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate it mathematically.

Compute the ratio between height & width of the image, then calculate the actual width of the image as displayed.

Subtract the image's actual width from the imageview's width, and divide by two.

This will give you the width of the grey area left of the image. Simply subtract this number from the X coordinates you got, and you will get the relative X position from the actual image.

Comment: I was thinking there would be a method for that in the Android API. Do you know of any? If not, no matter, I'll do it by hand. But I'd prefer something more generic...

Comment: Well, thanks anyway, see the updated question for how I did it ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with any such API.